# How can I compute spotlight attenuation when I only have a spotlight cutoff angle?

Tags: shaders, glsl, fragment-shader, webgl

I am trying to compute the spot light attenuation, though I don't have a `spotCosCutoff` (cosine of the spotlight cutoff angle) predefined variable in the shader so I have to compute it myself. This is the function that I am using now:

```
float spotLightAttenuation(vec3 L)  
{
    float theta= dot(normalize(spotDirection),-L);
    if(theta > cos(spotCutoff))
        return pow(max(theta,0.0),spotExponent);
    return 0.0;
}
```

But it doesn't really look like a spotlight. This is how it behaves (with a working, already tested, Phong shader) if the spot light direction is far from the light direction, with a low cutoff angle:

[image]

The cutoff angle is passed as a uniform, and it's `0.1` in this case. It is not really the angle between the spot direction and the end of the cone, it is an absolute angle. I should compute the `cosSpotCutoff` by making the dot product between the direction where the cone ends and the spot light direction, but since `spotCutoff` is just an angle, I'm not able to do it.

How do I convert it to a vector? Could anyone show me how to compute properly the attenuation?

Comment: What is L , is the vector from the pixel position to light ?

Comment: @Raxvan Yes....